# Relation between barycentric coordinates for triangles of order n and n + 1.

Tags: triangles, barycentric-coordinates

I am taking course in Finite Element Method, and we are looking at barycentric coordinates for triangles. It appears that there is a relation between the coordinates for point in triangle of order n and triangle of order n + 1. Given by this:

$$L_1^{(n)} = \frac{S_{P23}}{S_{123}}\\
L_1^{(n+1)} = \frac{S_{P2^*3}}{S_{1^*2^*3}}\\
\frac{L_1^{(n)}}{L_1^{(n+1)}}=\frac{S_{P23}}{S_{P2^*3}}*\frac{S_{1^*2^*3}}{S_{123}}=\frac{n}{n+1}*\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^2=\\
=\frac{n+1}{n} \Rightarrow L_1^{(n)}=\frac{n+1}{n}*L_1^{(n+1)}
$$

Where P is a point which lies in the triangles. So my question is how do we get this equation:
$$\frac{S_{P23}}{S_{P2^*3}}*\frac{S_{1^*2^*3}}{S_{123}}=\frac{n}{n+1}*\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^2$$